Non-generic function is failing
I have two versions of Retrieve() functions: generic and non-generic.
The non-generic version casts its arguments and calls the generic version.
        public TChild Retrieve((T, T, T) coordinates)
        {
            try
            {
                return grid_.Retrieve(coordinates);
            }
            catch { }
            return default(TChild);
        }

        public object Retrieve(object coordinates)
        {
            try
            {
                (T, T, T)? valueTuple = coordinates as (T, T, T)?;
                return Retrieve(valueTuple);
            }
            catch { }
            return default(TChild);
        }

 (T, T, T)? valueTuple = coordinates as (T, T, T)?; --- this line is always failing.
I.e., valueTuple is always receiving null after casting operations.
Why?  How can I fix it?
I am using C# 4.7.1 and Visual Studio 2017.

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // Initialize the grid with a dimension size (arbitrary)
            grid = new SpatialObjectGrid3DWithId<MockSpatialClass, int, MockSpatialClass, int, int>(10);

            // Insert some objects with known coordinates and IDs for retrieval testing
            grid.Insert((1, 2, 3), new MockSpatialClass { ID = 1, Coordinates = (1, 2, 3) });
            grid.Insert((4, 5, 6), new MockSpatialClass { ID = 2, Coordinates = (4, 5, 6) });
            grid.Insert((7, 8, 9), new MockSpatialClass { ID = 3, Coordinates = (7, 8, 9) });
        }


[TestMethod]
        public void Retrieve_ByObjectCoordinates_ReturnsCorrectObject()
        {
            var coordinates = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3);
            var result = (MockSpatialClass)grid.Retrieve((object)coordinates);
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, result.ID);
        }

public class SpatialObjectGrid3DWithId<TObj, TObjId, TChild, TChildId, T>
        where T : struct, IComparable<T>
        where TObj : class, ISpatialObject<TObj, TObjId, (T, T, T)>
        where TObjId : struct
        where TChild : class, ISpatialObject<TChild, TChildId, (T, T, T)>
        where TChildId : struct
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<TChildId, (T, T, T)> idDictionary_ = new Dictionary<TChildId, (T, T, T)>();
        private readonly SpatialHashGridWithMinMaxBounds3D<TChild, T> grid_;

        public SpatialObjectGrid3DWithId(int gridDim)
        {
            grid_ = new SpatialHashGridWithMinMaxBounds3D<TChild, T>(gridDim);
        }


        public TChild Retrieve((T, T, T) coordinates)
        {
            try
            {
                return grid_.Retrieve(coordinates);
            }
            catch { }
            return default(TChild);
        }

        public object Retrieve(object coordinates)
        {
            try
            {
                (T, T, T)? valueTuple = coordinates as (T, T, T)?;
                return Retrieve(valueTuple);
            }
            catch { }
            return default(TChild);
        }

... ... ... ...
}


Note: This is not a stack overflow. The function always returns null. return Retrieve(valueTuple); --- this line never executes.

Take out the try catches and see what the exception could be.  That's the first thing that comes to my mind.

@PaulCarlton as does not produce exceptions.

@GSerg- good point, I tend to directly cast.  Maybe that'll help because it seems like a type problem but it appears very subtle.

This is a stack overflow. Retrieve(object coordinates) calls Retrieve(object coordinates).

@GSerg, This is not a stack overflow. The function always returns null. return Retrieve(valueTuple); --- this line never executes.

@user366312 https://dotnetfiddle.net/ddxYWw

@PaulCarlton, I solved the problem by changing var coordinates = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3); into var coordinates = (1, 2, 3);

Though boxing a struct is less efficient. If the caller has to know typeof(T) why have the object version of the method at all?

Don't use the (T,T,T) notation - it is a ValueTuple, not a Tuple.
So, when you trying to cast a Tuple into the ValueTuple, the cast fails. Use explicit Tuple<T,T,T> everywhere and it should work.
Or vice versa, use the ValueTuple<T,T,T> everywhere or implement the both checks (for Tuple and ValueTuple). But anyway, you still can get some non-trivial object, for example something like the object of anonymous type (var a = new {X=1,Y=2,Z=3};) and it will fail again.
